# A few questions about the Go Language

Tags: programming-languages, go

I have a few questions about the Go programming language:

1. How is the addition of int and float variables implemented in the language?
2. is there a diffrence between the last question and the addition of int and float literals (for instance 3+2.1)?
3. What are all the sequencers in the Go language?

Comment: Smells like homework, and multiple questions bundled into one question.

Comment: Moral concerns aside, there are plenty of homework questions on StackOverflow. However, there should be no more than one question per post.

Comment: @Chris:  I have no moral problem with "help me with my homework", but this is closer to "do my homework for me".  I believe the consensus on SO is that homework is fine, but should be tagged appropriately.

Comment: abelenky: I fail to understand the problem with people acquiring help on homework from forums such as this one. After searching the Internet and forums and failing to achieve an answer about the NEW and less known language go I turned here. If that is a problem I would appreciate it being written in the forum's rules. About the multiple questions I agree and would avoid doing it again. Being overly righteous in an open forum is, in my opinion, out of place. I would like to thank all who did try to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There aren't implicit type conversions; you will have to explicitly decide which sort of addition you want and convert one or both operands to the relevant type.
2. You could answer this by simple experimentation.

   ```
   package main
   import "fmt"
   func main() {
       var i int = 3 + 2
       var f float = 3 + 2.1
       fmt.Printf("%d %f\n", i, f)
   }
   ```

   If you try replacing the 2 with 2.1, the code does not compile.
3. What do you mean by 'sequencers'?

Answer (score 4):

For the answers to your questions read [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html).

For example, for the first two questions start by reading the sections on [Numeric types](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Numeric_types), [Arithmetic operators](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Arithmetic_operators), and [Conversions](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Conversions).

For the third question, start by reading the [Statements](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Statements) sections and the section on [Handling panics](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Handling_panics).

Comment: I was looking through these documnets but unfortunately I still havne't understood how the operation of int and float addition takes place (How it is implemented in the language). Furthermore and I'm sorry for being tedious: what are sequencers??

Answer (score 0):

After close examination and help from colleagues I found an answer to the third question:
Sequencers are a construct that varies the normal flow of control.
particularly in go the sequencers are:

1. goto
2. Break
3. continue
4. return
5. fallthrough
6. go
7. defer
8. and panic (exception).
   Thanks all for the help.

Comment: An if-then-else statement is not a sequencer?